# Identifying all rows within a table <tbody> element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to retrieve all rows from within a `<tbody>` section of a table, but am unsure of the syntax for doing so. I've included a dummy table extract below and my latest attempt for achieving the task with jQuery!

**Table extract:**

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <th id="emergency" colspan="2">Emergency</th>
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emergency data</td>
      <td>Emergency data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emergency data</td>
      <td>Emergency data</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody> 
 <tr>
  <th id="urgent" colspan="2">Urgent</th>
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Urgent Data</td>
      <td>Urgent Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Urgent Data</td>
      <td>Urgent Data</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
var emergencyRows = $table.find('#emergency').children().get();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My suggestions is to place the ID attributes on the tbody rather than the first row of each one.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody id="emergency">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Emergency</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Emergency data</td>
            <td>Emergency data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Emergency data</td>
            <td>Emergency data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="urgent">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Urgent</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Urgent Data</td>
            <td>Urgent Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Urgent Data</td>
            <td>Urgent Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
var emergencyRows = $("tbody#emergency").find("tr:gt(0)");
var urgentRows = $("tbody#urgent").find("tr:gt(0)");
```

The jQuery snippet will get all the respective rows with the exception of the first rows.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the below if you know the table id.

```
var trs = $("#tableid").find("tbody>tr");
```

Comment: If we have applied pagination,then how do I get other page data besides of current page.

Comment: I was able to find a solution to get all records in paginated pages.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the cleanest

```
$('#emergency').closest('tbody').children(); //only returns first child element, so the <tr>'s
```

Answer (score 3):

From your example, it seems like you might want "all rows except for the one containing #emergency".  If that's the case, you can use the following:

`$('#emergency').closest('tr').siblings();`

Note that `#emergency` need not be a `<tr />` or `<th />` or anything in particular.  It could be any element within a table cell.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var emergencyRows = $("th#emergency").parent().parent().find("tr:gt(0)");
```

which should get you all rows that aren't the header row.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to get all records in paginated pages.You also can try out this.

`var userList = $("#user-grid").dataTable().fnGetNodes();`